# Understanding `modifyMVar_`

Tags: haskell

Given:

```
λ: >let m = newMVar "foo"

λ: >m >>= readMVar 
"foo"
```

I tried to use `modifyMVar_`:

```
λ: >:t modifyMVar_
modifyMVar_ :: MVar a -> (a -> IO a) -> IO ()
```

through:

```
λ: >m >>= \mvar -> modifyMVar_ mvar (\_ -> return "bar")
```

But, it doesn't look like it modified `m` from `"foo"` to `"bar"`.

```
λ: >m >>= readMVar 
"foo"
```

What'd I do wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you write it all in one line? `m >>= \mvar -> modifyMVar_ mvar (\_ -> return "bar") >> readMVar`?

Comment: I'd recommend you read about [`let` vs `<-`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624408/equal-vs-left-arrow-symbols-in-haskell). Above you used `let` when you meant `<-`, I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting off a interval on application launch in a Haskell Servant app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959753/setting-off-a-interval-on-application-launch-in-a-haskell-servant-app)

Comment: @jberryman that question's code is so much more involved though. here it is simple, short. also, the setting and specific types are different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`m` creates new `MVar` with `"foo"` every time it's called. You're modifying one `MVar` then making a new one and checking that. It is the same problem as seen here [Setting off a interval on application launch in a Haskell Servant app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959753/setting-off-a-interval-on-application-launch-in-a-haskell-servant-app) with exception that there it was an `IORef`.

```
myVar <- m
modifyMVar_ myVar (\_ -> return "bar")
readMVar myVar
```

This should give you `"bar"` as expected.

Comment: Phrased differently. `m` is not an MVar.